# sample_frac function of dplyr is giving back an error

Tags: r, dplyr

I would be very grateful for your help in solving this problem.  I want to:
1. understand why that happened
2. solve that problem and using sample_frac function of dplyr.

I'm using
`sample_frac(ecom, size = 0.7)`

- **Expected result**
  Load 70% of my data of the ecom dataset.
- **Given result**

  ```
  Error: n() should only be called in a data context  
  Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
  ```
- Error trace

  ```
  > rlang::last_trace()  
       x
    1. +-dplyr::sample_frac(ecom, size = 0.7)
    2. +-dplyr:::sample_frac.data.frame(ecom, size = 0.7)
    3. | +-dplyr::slice(...)
    4. | \-dplyr:::slice.tbl_df(...)
    5. |   \-dplyr:::slice_impl(.data, quo)
    6. +-sample.int(...)
    7. +-base::sample.int(...)
    8. \-dplyr::n()
    9.   \-dplyr:::from_context("..group_size")
   10.     \-`%||%`(...)
  ```
- Session info

  ```
  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)  
  Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  
  Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)  

  Matrix products: default  

  locale:  
  [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252     
  [3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
  [5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

  attached base packages:  
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

  other attached packages:
  [1] readr_1.3.1 dplyr_0.8.3


  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  
   [1] compiler_3.5.1  magrittr_1.5    tools_3.5.1     htmltools_0.3.6  
   [5] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.1      stringi_1.4.3   rmarkdown_1.14   
   [9] highr_0.8       knitr_1.23      stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.8       
  [13] digest_0.6.20   evaluate_0.14
  ```

Comment: It's hard to help when we don't know what your data looks like. Your basic syntax seems fine, assuming `ecom` is a frame (or tibble), so either it's not a frame, is not a *simple* frame, or something else is going on.

Comment: @r2evans, it's a list: > typeof(ecom)
[1] "list"

Comment: `sample_frac` only works on frames, not lists. Unfortunately, the error I see from `sample_frac(list(a=1:99,b=1:99), size=0.1)` is different from the error you provided, so your object is not simply a list.

Comment: @r2evans, that was also what I thought. So I did this: > myDF <- as.data.frame(ecom) and > class(myDF) showed me this result: [1] "data.frame".  But the error stays the same: > Error: n() should only be called in a data context

Comment: It works for me with `sample_frac(mtcars, size=0.1)`, so the problem is with your frame. The only way we can help is if we see an unambiguous and representative sample of your data, such as with `dput(head(myDF))`.

Comment: @r2evans, I used your example: > sample_frac(mtcars, size=0.1) but the error stays the same: > Error: n() should only be called in a data context

Comment: Looks like a name space/ packages conflict to me. Running dplyr::sample_frac() probably doesn’t resolve this issue - I think it is the n() function which is called from sample_frac. My advise would be to unload all additional packages except from dplyr, then perform sample_frac and then load needed packages again. Good luck.

Comment: I'm running `dplyr-0.8.0.1` currently, so perhaps it's a regression. I'm not in an immediate position to update (untested), so I think I'm unable to help any further, sorry. I hope somebody else can chime in with something.

Comment: @squeezer44 can you give us `dput` of your dataset?

Comment: @TimTeaFan : I've detached all packages except datasets, dplyr and base and rerun > sample_frac(mtcars, size=0.1) but the error stays the same: > sample_frac(mtcars, size=0.1) 
Error: n() should only be called in a data context . So my assumption: it seems to be related to my version dplyr_0.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved:
After detach all packages except datasets, dplyr and base I had quit the Rsession. After opened a new Rsession and reload all packages I had before the error occured it ran properly:

```
> sample_frac(mtcars, size=0.1)
```

mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
2 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
3 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4